# phppgadmin login failed

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, phppgadmin

I've tried numerous methods on various posts and docs but I think I'm missing something... I just cannot login to phppgadmin using my browser. I even created a database from the terminal but I just can't seem to login using phppgadmin. It says login failed.

Does anyone else have the same problem or at least a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your username will be : postgres and password whatever you entered in terminal while creating user role and database